# Inrush current and number of devices per MCB

Tags: led, current, driver, transient

I'm looking at some LED drivers meant to be powered by the regular mains voltage (230V). The datasheet specifies how many drivers can be connected to a single Miniature Circuit Breaker (MCB) on account of the inrush current and specifies the basic outline of the inrush current itself.

So, three values are always given on these driver-types' datasheets:

- The peak value of the inrush current (A).
- The duration of the inrush current measured at 50% of the peak level (µs).
- The amount of drivers allowed on a type-B 16A MCB.

For most applications the amount of drivers per MCB is enough information - but i'm wondering (mostly for curiosity's sake)  if it is possible to calculate the amount of drivers per MCB GIVEN the information about the inrush current (peak and duration)? Or if more information about the inrush current is needed?

Also, is it possible to "combine" the inrush current of two different types of drivers?

Answer (score 0):

The driver data given and the circuit breaker curves should be sufficient to determine how many can be connected. You should me able to add the currents together. If there is more than one kind of driver with different inrush durations, the addition would be a little more complex. All of the drivers connected simultaneously would probably represent the worst case, but you might need to evaluate the effect of individual or groups of drivers connected in rapid sequence.